# Prove the series $\sum u_n(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\cdots$ converges uniformly on every bounded subset of $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, exponential-sum

Let $[-t,t]$ be the bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ for $t>0$.

Let $\varepsilon$ be given. Then $\exists$ $ m\in \mathbb N$ such that for any $p \in \mathbb N$ & $x \in[-t,t]$, we get

$$\left| \frac{x^n}{n!}\right| < \left| \frac{t^n}{n!}\right|<\frac \varepsilon p \quad \forall n\ge m. \tag 1$$

Now considering,

$$
\begin{align}
\left| u_{n+p}-u_n\right| & =\left| \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+\frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+p}}{(n+p)!} \right| \\[8pt]
& {} \le \left| \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right| + \left| \frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}\right| + \left| \frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}\right| +\cdots+ \left| \frac{x^{n+p}}{(n+p)!} \right| \tag 2
\end{align}
$$

(where $u_n=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+ \cdots +\frac{x^n}{n!}$)

From (1) & (2) $\forall n\ge m$ & $\forall p\in \mathbb N$, we have

$$\left| \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right|+ \left| \frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}\right| + \left| \frac{x^{n+3}}{(n+3)!}\right| +\cdots+ \left| \frac{x^{n+p}}{(n+p)!} \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{p} \cdot p= \varepsilon$$

Hence by Cauchy's Principle $\sum u_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-t,t]$. Since $t>0$ is arbitrary $\sum u_n(x)$ converges uniformly on any bounded subset of $\mathbb R$.

**Is My Solution Correct? Can this be done by Weierstrass' M-test? Why this series is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$?**

Comment: This is the exponential function

Comment: @YuriyS:This is the exponential series.

Comment: @Michael Hardy:Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the $M$-test and then the ratio test.

The function converges uniformly on every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. 
 In Particular, fix a radius of convergence, R.

Then $$|\frac{x^n}{n!}| \leq \frac{R^n}{n!}$$

Let $A_n=\frac{R^n}{n!}$, and now you need only show thaat $\sum_{n \geq 0} A_n$ converges.

Try the ratio test, which asserts that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}=L<1$, then the series will converge absolutely,  morally since it will eventually be less than a convergent geometric series.

Comment: :I get your point.But,here we are talking about $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The argument does not change at all.

Comment: :Earler what you've written is right?If yes,how can we prove that the function converges uniformly on every bounded subset of $\Bbb C$?Any hints are welcome.

Comment: :Will you please  judge my comment below Robert Israel's post?

Comment: In my answer, I tell you how to do it.

Comment: My first step indeed uses the M-test

Answer (score 0):

A power series $\sum_n a_n z^n$ with radius of convergence $R$ converges uniformly on $\{z: |z| \le r\}$ if $r < R$.  In this case $R = \infty$.

Comment: :This  is the reason,why  exponential series converges for every bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: :Can this be done using Weierstrass' M-Test?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not correct. You state an inequality for every $p$ (after having chosen m) and that is wrong. You may use Weierstrass M-test.
Given your $t>0$ choose an integer $m > 2t$. Then
$$ \sum_{n\geq m} \frac{t^n}{n!} \leq \frac{t^m}{m!} \sum_{k\geq 0} \left( \frac{t}{m}\right)^k \leq\frac{t^m}{m!} \sum_{k\geq 0} 1/2^k \leq  2\frac{t^m}{m!} $$

Comment: :I've chosen $m$ after choosing $p$.

Comment: :How does these inequalities came?

Comment: Just before (1) p is chosen after m. And the argument below that is (really) wrong. Anyway, in my estimate when $m>2t$ we have for $n\geq m$ that $t/2n\leq 1/2$ which I then inserted (I also wrote $n=m+k$ with $k\geq 0$). But you may also use ratio test or other to show convergence

Comment: :I'm not getting your point.Will you please make the suitable changes in O.P. so that it becomes correct?

Comment: The statement in the OP is beyond repair. What you say in (1), and really use below that, is that there is $m$ so for any $n\geq m$ and ANY $p$ you have the given estimate. Letting $p\rightarrow \infty$ the LHS must be zero, which is not the case. The problem in the last inequality is that you try to use  a uniform bound on all $p$ terms (for arbitrary $p$) and that does not work. Again if each term was smaller than $\epsilon/p$ for any $p$ then they must all be zero.